# [mntent]: line 15 in /etc/fstab is bad

Tags: linux, mount, samba, fstab

it works fine mounting manually from the cli

but when running

```
sudo mount -a
```

after editing the fstab im getting errors. It seems right to me, any one have a suggestion.

my fstab is:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.                                                       
#                                                                                                   
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a                                      
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices                          
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).                                     
#                                                                                                   
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>                              
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0                               
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation                                                            
UUID=31c241fa-8ce7-4ddf-a11b-c1bb7214b9ff /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1       
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation                                                         
UUID=f6adc6f2-a8ac-46cc-a167-fd5bdb985ca7 none            swap    sw              0       0         
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0                          

//megaboxy/inetpub /mnt/megabo cifs username=admin, password=passwd 0 0                 
//megaboxz/inetpub /mnt/megab cifs username=admin, password=passwd 0 0                 
//10.0.0.15/Share  /mnt/CodeS cifs username=admin, password=passwd 0 0                
//210.0.0.1/inetpub   /mnt/webse cifs username=admin, password=passwd 0 0                
//10.0.0.120/Kabura-Projects  /mnt/Projects  cifs username=admin, password=passwd 0 0
```

Comment: Probably network failure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
//megaboxy/inetpub /mnt/megabo cifs username=admin, password=passwd 0 0
                                                   ^ this is a problem
```

You can't put spaces between the options. Remove that and that error should go avay.

Comment: ty whitespace deamon

Answer (score 1):

Add `noauto` option for all cifs system, and execute `mount -a -t cifs` after network service.

As you didn't mention your distro, this step could vary.